# What can we do to this [dymamic] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I came across this tag: [dymamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dymamic)

How can this be cleaned up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nice catch. I didn't even notice at first that this is a typo tag, one that dates all the way back to 2009.

Definitely don't just remove the tag, but replace it with the correct one, [dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic). As always, make sure you fix any other problems that you see with each question you edit, and vote to close (or delete) where appropriate so off-topic questions get into the right review queue.

Answer (score -4):

While there are a literal handful of these questions, we should look to edit them into shape (or VTC and *not* remove the tag) as we go through this.  There are too few to go through the formal process, but some kind of rigor is expected here.